# Django - testing emails with the outbox using post_office

Tags: python, django, django-email, django-postoffice

I'm writing tests for an application that uses the [django-post_office](https://github.com/ui/django-post_office) package for most of its email functionality.

The default `django.core.mail` library contains plenty of useful tools for testing whether or not there are actually emails being sent. (Without actually sending any during the tests)

```
class TestFunctionThatSendsEmail(Testcase):

   @override_settings(
        EMAIL_BACKEND='django.core.mail.backends.locmem.EmailBackend'
   )
   def test_function_sends_email(self):
       self.assertEqual(len(outbox), 0)
       run_function_that_calls_email()
       self.assertEqual(len(outbox), 1)
       ...
       # other tests
```

However, the emails in our function are being sent with the `django-post_office` `mail.send()` function

```
# priority now to make sure that they are being sent right away
mail.send(
        sender=sender,
        recipients=to,
        context=context,
        template=template_name,
        priority='now',
    )
```

Which causes the test above to fail as for some reason the emails do not end up in the outbox.

The strange thing is that if I change the `EMAIL_BACKEND` to `django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend` the emails do show up in my terminal, so it is listening to the `EMAIL_BACKEND` settings.

I've tried finding alternative methods / functions to test this functionality in the `django-post_office` github, but all I could find was the advice to check to see if the emails are saved to the database and verify their status. (Which I did and works) but the fact that django seems to be unable to detect any emails actually being sent is making me a little bit nervous.

Does anyone know of a way to make emails sent by `django-post_office` appear in the outbox or, if that is not possible, a way to make sure that they are actually being sent? (beyond checking the database)

Comment: did you ever find an answer to this? I have the same issue.

Comment: Unfortunately I did not. I ended up on mocking our 'send_email'  function (which itself contains the call to the post_office_mail.send() function) and verifying that the call was made with the right arguments - thus implicitly trusting the postoffice package to work as it should.

Comment: The other option is to get the `email` object from the `Email` model, and test `self.assertEqual(email.status, STATUS.sent)`. This at least tells you `self.email_message()` returned under `dispatch()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that `django-post_office` stores the mail backend in the `Email` object:

```
class Email(models.Model):
    backend_alias = models.CharField(_("Backend alias"), blank=True, default='',
                                     max_length=64)
```

When `dispatch()` is called, it uses this backend.

When creating an email, DPO overrides `create()` to set the backend from `def get_available_backends()`, which looks up the backend in the `settings` conf.

This means that using `@override_settings(EMAIL_BACKEND='django.core.mail.backends.locmem.EmailBackend')` won't set the `backend_alias` in the `Email` object correctly.

Instead you need to do this manually when you create the object, as per the dispatch test:

```
def test_dispatch(self):
    """
    Ensure that email.dispatch() actually sends out the email
    """
    email = Email.objects.create(to=['to@example.com'], from_email='from@example.com',
                                 subject='Test dispatch', message='Message', backend_alias='locmem')
    email.dispatch()
    self.assertEqual(mail.outbox[0].subject, 'Test dispatch')
```

If you are using `mail.send()` you can simply pass the `mail.send(backend='locmem')` as an argument; make sure you have `locmem': 'django.core.mail.backends.locmem.EmailBackend'` in your `POST_OFFICE` settings

Comment: You can of course just override `'BACKENDS': {'default': 'django.core.mail.backends.locmem.EmailBackend'},` in `POST_OFFICE`

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue as you described and fixed it by setting the `DEFAULT_PRIORITY` to `'now'`:

```py
class TestFunctionThatSendsEmail(Testcase):

   @override_settings(
        POST_OFFICE={
            'BACKENDS': {'default': 'django.core.mail.backends.locmem.EmailBackend'},
            'DEFAULT_PRIORITY': 'now',
        }
   )
   def test_function_sends_email(self):
       self.assertEqual(len(outbox), 0)
       run_function_that_calls_email()
       self.assertEqual(len(outbox), 1)
       ...
       # other tests
```